# Get the current row index of WPF DataGrid in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

How can I get the current selected row index of WPF data grid in XAML. I know how to get current row index in code behind. But i want to get the selected row index to pass it as command parameter, so that I can delete the corresponding itemfrom the collection, passing the index.

I've tried `CommandParameter="{Binding Items.CurrentPosition, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"`, but it is not working(giving **-1** as selectedindex). Is it possible to get the current row index in XAML, if yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works okay for me, I use this on a button within a row:

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyClickRowEventCommand,       
   RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor,
   AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
   CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=DataContext}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=YourDataGridName,Path=SelectedItem}"
```

After that you can delete the SelectedItem from the collection